# PHP unlink doesn't delete

Tags: php, forms, post, dynamic, unlink

This tiny problem has ruined my day. I can't delete files by PHP `unlink` function. I am creating PHP form to update and edit pdf files. Below is my piece of html form and PHP `unlink` script.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" value="<?php echo $row['img']?>" name="image">
<input type="submit" name="update">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']) && ($_FILES['image']['name'])){
$image=$_POST['image'];
unlink('../pdf/services/'.$image);
}

?>
```

Comment: Where does `$_POST['image']` come from?

Comment: very not secure! does apache have write permissions? Is the path correct and file exist?

Comment: what is the return value from unlink that you are getting? possibly permission issue. Use `chmod` to set appropriate permissions.

Comment: If `image` is an `<input type="file">`, you're looking for `$_FILES['image']['name']` instead of `$_POST['image']`. But please add some security checks around this.

Comment: If I were to post `../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd` in the "image" key what would happen?

Comment: @GordonM Hopefully, Apache would get a "Permission denied" error ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$image = $_FILES['image']['name'])`?

Comment: I tried it, but doesn't work. @apokryfos

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_FILES`. Something like
`$image = $_FILES['image'];` and then `$imgname = $image['name'];`

After that you can use `unlink();` as you wanted (`unlink("../pdf/services".$imgname);`)

Hope I helped, It worked after my tests!

Comment: I tried by your way, but it doesn't work, still file is existed in folder.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try to remove a file using `unlink`, you will need to make sure that everything is ok:

1. Is the path I want to remove a file from available? Do I have access all the folders I need along the path? If not, then giving the necessary privileges will be needed.
2. Is my location the one I think it is? You will need to run `getcwd()` which is current working directory. If your page is not in the desired location, then compared to it the path you want to reach will mean a different thing
3. Is adding the path I want to the location I got at the second point correct and the one I expect?

If everything above is all right and you still have the problem, then check the error log, it might give you helpful information. If the problem still persists, then you will need to create a dummy file on the path you want to remove the other file from. Is the file created? Is it created at the correct location?

Comment: file path and location is correct. I already tested by using echo function... It prints correct file name. New file is uploaded properly.      `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"../pdf/services/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);` but can't unlink.

Comment: @DipakOjha Can you check whether the new file is in the same folder as the file to be removed? If so, can you remove the new file using unlink?